# Optimization (indexing?) for ORDER BY COUNT with postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, query-performance, postgresql-9.5

Here is a simple query to get the `projects` list ordered by `participations` count.

```
SELECT projects.*, COUNT(participations) as ct from projects
  INNER JOIN participations ON participations.project_id=projects.id
  GROUP BY projects.id
ORDER BY ct DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

I'm not astonished it's slow (2 seconds). A simple query without ordering by `participations` count, is super speed (it's normal, ~10ms).

There are ~2k `projects` and ~430k `participations`.

What should I do to speed up this request? I feel I have to add an index, but I don't know which one(s?) and how.

**EDIT:**

Table `paticipations`:

```
create table participations
(
    id serial not null
        constraint participations_pkey
            primary key,
    project_id integer not null
        constraint participations_project_id_foreign
            references projects
        constraint participations_service_id_foreign
            references projects,
    status varchar(32) default 'unknown'::character varying not null,
    data jsonb,
    created_at timestamp(0),
    updated_at timestamp(0),
    deleted_at timestamp(0)
);

create index participations_status_index on participations (status);
create index participation_data_idx on participations (data);
```

Table `projects`:

```
create table projects
(
    id serial not null
        constraint services_pkey
            primary key,
    user_id integer not null
        constraint services_user_id_foreign
            references users,
    type varchar(50) not null,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    url varchar(255) not null,
    start_at timestamp(0),
    end_at timestamp(0),
    visibility varchar(255) not null,
    status varchar(255) not null,
    metadata jsonb not null,
    data jsonb not null,
    created_at timestamp(0),
    updated_at timestamp(0),
    deleted_at timestamp(0)
);

create index services_type_index on projects (type);
create index services_name_index on projects (name);
create index services_url_index on projects (url);
create index services_start_at_index on projects (start_at);
create index services_end_at_index on projects (end_at);
create index services_visibility_index on projects (visibility);
create index services_status_index on projects (status);
```

Query plan:

```
Limit  (cost=487359.41..487359.43 rows=5 width=2218) (actual time=2177.264..2177.265 rows=5 loops=1)
Buffers: shared hit=37446 read=3493, temp read=21051 written=39402
->  Sort  (cost=487359.41..487366.68 rows=2907 width=2218) (actual time=2177.262..2177.262 rows=5 loops=1)
        Sort Key: (count(participations.*)) DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 33kB
        Buffers: shared hit=37446 read=3493, temp read=21051 written=39402
        ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=477474.47..487311.13 rows=2907 width=2218) (actual time=1170.136..2175.445 rows=1884 loops=1)
            Group Key: projects.id
            Buffers: shared hit=37446 read=3493, temp read=21051 written=39402
            ->  Merge Join  (cost=477474.47..485105.80 rows=435252 width=2218) (actual time=1170.122..2120.557 rows=435207 loops=1)
                    Merge Cond: (projects.id = participations.project_id)
                    Buffers: shared hit=37446 read=3493, temp read=21051 written=39402
                    ->  Sort  (cost=625.30..632.57 rows=2907 width=1131) (actual time=22.443..27.047 rows=2879 loops=1)
                        Sort Key: projects.id
                        Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 3216kB
                        Buffers: shared hit=429, temp read=402 written=402
                        ->  Seq Scan on projects  (cost=0.00..458.07 rows=2907 width=1131) (actual time=0.011..1.532 rows=2879 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=429
                    ->  Materialize  (cost=476849.12..479025.38 rows=435252 width=1091) (actual time=1147.671..1996.166 rows=435207 loops=1)
                        Buffers: shared hit=37017 read=3493, temp read=20649 written=39000
                        ->  Sort  (cost=476849.12..477937.25 rows=435252 width=1091) (actual time=1147.666..1400.856 rows=435207 loops=1)
                                Sort Key: participations.project_id
                                Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 165040kB
                                Buffers: shared hit=37017 read=3493, temp read=20649 written=20649
                                ->  Seq Scan on participations  (cost=0.00..19528.52 rows=435252 width=1091) (actual time=0.012..318.347 rows=435207 loops=1)
                                    Buffers: shared hit=37017 read=3493
Planning time: 1.309 ms
Execution time: 2203.249 ms
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes), the query you are using and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ok, done.

Comment: These FK constraints don't look  like they would work.(you could use the output of `\dt your_table_name` instead) Also: foreign keys need a supporting index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `order by` cannot use an index, because it is based on a calculated value.

I might suggest doing the `order by` and `limit` in a subquery:

```
SELECT pr.*, p.ct 
FROM projects pr JOIN
     (SELECT p.project_id, COUNT(*) as ct
      FROM participations p
      GROUP BY p.project_id
      ORDER BY ct DESC
      LIMIT 5
     ) p
     ON p.project_id = pr.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to aggregate first, then join on the aggregation:

```
SELECT projects.*, pt.ct 
from projects 
  join (
    select project_id, count(*) as ct 
    from participations 
    GROUP BY project_id
  ) pt ON pt.project_id = projects.id
ORDER BY ct DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Also: all your sorts are done on disk. If you increase [work_mem](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-WORK-MEM) this should also improve performance.